# Multiple criteria search using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, hql, hibernate-criteria

I am setting up a search function to allow me to find users who have specific skills.

The following is my User Object:

```
public class User {
  private int id;
  private String email;
  private String name;
  private Set userSkills = new HashSet(0);

  -- getters/setters --
}
```

and the following is the Skill Object:

```
public class Skill {
  private int id;
  private String skillName;

  -- getters/setters --
}
```

and finally the UserSkill Object, which is mapped to the user_skill table that manages the many to many relationship between User and Skill

```
public class UserSkill {
  private int id;
  private int userId;
  private int skillId;

  -- getters/setters --
}
```

Now the requirement is to find a list of users who have subscribed to skill id 13, 29 and 31.

My attempt is the following:

```
Query q = session.createQuery(
                "from User as user " +
                "left join fetch user.userSkills as us " +
                "where us.skill = 13 AND us.skill = 29 AND us.skill = 31");

        list = (ArrayList<User>) q.list();
```

The above does not work as the list being returned is always empty, despite there being users who are subscribed to Skills of id 13, 29 and 31.

Can someone please suggest the right HQL or if perhaps this should be done using the Hibernate Criteria API? Please help me out by posting examples or pointing me to a link with examples!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line:

```
where us.skill = 13 AND us.skill = 29 AND us.skill = 31
```

to

```
where us.skillId in (13,29,31)
```

P.S. Also remove `= new HashSet(0)`

Comment: This did not work unfortunately. I am still retrieving an empty list.